# Highcharts columns height in phantomjs generated pdf

Tags: highcharts, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I am trying to generate a pdf with phantomjs from a page that's using highcharts. This is the script I am using

```
var port, server, service

system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
console.log(msg);
trace.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
})
}

var fs = require('fs');
function loadFile(name){
if(fs.exists(name)){
    console.log(name+ " File  exist");
    return fs.open(name,"r");
}else {
    console.log("File do not exist");
}
}

if (system.args.length !== 2) {
console.log('Usage: serverkeepalive.js <portnumber>');
phantom.exit(1);
} else {
port = system.args[1];
console.log('port: ' + port);
server = require('webserver').create();

service = server.listen(port, { keepAlive: true }, function (request, response) {
    console.log('Request at ' + new Date());
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
    console.log('ProjectId:' + request.headers.projectId)
    var projectReportPage = 'http://localhost:55073/' + request.headers.projectId;

    console.log(projectReportPage);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.cookies, null, 4));

    phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
    phantom.addCookie({
        'name':     'hello',   /* required property */
        'value':    'helloFromPhantomJS',  /* required property */
        'domain':   'localhost',           /* required property */
        'expires':  (new Date()).getTime() + 3600   /* <- expires in 1 hour */
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies, null, 4));

    page.paperSize = {
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    margin:'1cm' };

    page.open(projectReportPage, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        } else {
            console.log('Page obtained');
            var reportName = 'report_' + request.headers.projectId + '.pdf';
            page.evaluate( function(){$('h1').css('color', 'red');});
            page.render(reportName);
            var body = fs.absolute(reportName);
            //var body = page.renderBase64('pdf');
            // var fi = loadFile(reportName);
            // var body = fi.read();
            // var rawBody = fs.read(reportName);
            // console.log(rawBody);
            // var body = base64Encode(rawBody);
            console.log(body);
            response.statusCode = 200;
            response.headers = {
                'Cache': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
                'Content-Length': body.length
            };
            response.write(body);
            response.close();
        }
    });
    console.log('After page open handler');
});

if (service) {
    console.log('Web server running on port ' + port);
} else {
    console.log('Error: Could not create web server listening on port ' + port);
    phantom.exit();
}
}
```

When viewing the page, the chart looks like this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4tJn.png

This is what it looks like on the pdf:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLLTt.png

Any insights on why this happens would be appreciated!

Comment: It turns out that it was the highcharts initialisation animation that was causing the problem. The page was being rendered before the animation could complete

Comment: Yes, disable animations and should be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that PhantomJS immediately takes a snapshot when the page is loaded. However, the Highcharts graph has an animation which builds up the graph.

This means the graph is not completely built up when PhantomJS is taking the snapshot. There are two possible solutions.

#### 1. Skip the Highcharts animations

Add this to your graph configuration object.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13832029/363448)

#### 2. Add a delay when taking a snapshot

```
page.open(address, function (status) {
   window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14380411/363448)

Comment: Did not mark your comment as the response as it was added one month after my comment which contains the response. But thanks for the contribution!